# get a string php regex match

Tags: php, regex

here is my string

0 12 10 0 5 0 albert 126 al br t 881 alert 58 a lbr t 317 apart 251 al b rt 284 ambit 165 a lb rt 9 album 93 a l br t 881 10 6 13 0 einstein 92 en stein 219 epstein 8 e n stein 335 eastern 62 ens t ein 317 enshrin 13 en st ein 231 enseign 3 ens tei n 203 **false albert einstein 154** albert einstein (al br t) einstein 1030 al br t einstein albert (en stein) 318 albert en stein albert epstein 134 albert epstein alert einstein 139 alert einstein

I need to get the value in between false and the number next to the words.. in the above case I require

...`false albert einstein 154`... => `albert einstein`

I tried the below regex match, but its not working. What am I missing here?

```
$matches=array();
preg_match('/false=([a-z]+)\[0-9]+/', $response, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Comment: Why are you escaping `\[` the character class? That will not make the number matching work. And your example text contains spaces that you do not account for. And why does your regex look for a `=` after the `false`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a pattern like this:

```
false\s*(.+?)\s*[0-9]+
```

This will match:

- `false` - the literal string `false`
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespace characters
- `(.+?)` - one or more of any character, non-greedily, captured in group 1
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespace characters
- `[0-9]+` - one or more decimal digits

For example:

```
$input = 'false albert einstein 154';
preg_match('/false\s*(.+?)\s*[0-9]+/', $input, $matches);
echo $matches[1]; // 'albert einstein'
```

Comment: <some characters><space>false<required text><space><number><some characters> is how the input will be..

Comment: @Naren Then you've done something wrong. I've tested this exact code and it works.

Comment: @Naren, don't you think providing us the ***exact*** input is ***very important?***

Comment: I provided the same input, the problem was, I got the content from a server using file_get_contents. When I echoed it and copy pasted it from browser to the code it worked. But it did not when I directly assigned as input string to preg_match.

Comment: If it's possible there is a line break between the `false` and `154` you may need to use the single-line flag (`s`) -- i.e. `/false\s*(.+?)\s*[0-9]+/s`

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me:

```
$response = ".false albert einstein 154.";
$matches=array();
preg_match('/.*?false ([a-z\s]+) (?=[0-9]{3}).*/', $response, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```